# rust sqlx-cli: how to prepare offline mode for queries in tests

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-sqlx

I use some https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx `query!` macros in my tests, and I need to be able to run [`cargo sqlx prepare`](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/tree/ce801b933006c422ada464d0663c68dcf6c680d4/sqlx-cli#enable-building-in-offline-mode-with-query) for them so my IDE can expand the macros and provide type information (autocomplete, etc.).

But if I just run `cargo sqlx prepare`, all code behind `#[cfg(test)]` is ignored.

How can I tell cargo/sqlx to analyse my tests too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cargo sqlx prepare -- --tests` does the trick

(`--tests` is passed to `cargo rustc`, which makes it build all tests)